# How to calculate the position of point C that has a specific distance to A?

Tags: swift

I have two points: A and B. I know how to calculate the angle between the two points and create a line.

```
 func angle(p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat{
    return atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
 }
```

now I'm wondering how can I calculate the coordinates of a third point that has a given distance to point A?

[image]

Comment: I don’t know I m right or not. If you substrate distance from point then I think you will get answers

Answer (score 0):

You are totally right about the angle. After you calculated the angle, you can continue with calculating the relative offset with the distance.

```swift
let xOffset = distance * cos(angle)
let yOffset = distance * sin(angle)
```

In your case the distance is relative to point A, so the coordinates of point C are going to be:

```swift
C.x = A.x - xOffset
C.y = A.y - yOffset
```